# Android Wear OS with Google Fitness API

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, google-api-client, fitness

I have an application with package name: com.x, and I created a module wear OS with package name com.x.watch.
I created a separate project for each on firebase linked to Google API console. I enabled the Fitness API, added the correct Sha-1, and ouath client with a test user.
Whenever I run the mobile application, I am able to retrieve the steps. However, when I run the watch application, I always receive the following error:

```
W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Fitness.RECORDING_CLIENT is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INVALID_ACCOUNT, resolution=null, message=null}
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zap.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:2)
```